# $\lim_{x\to0}\cos\frac2x$ by the squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm stuck in using the squeeze theorem to find
$$\lim_{x\to0}\cos\frac2x$$
Any detailed answers would be encouraged. In addition, my instructor gave me a hint that I should prove $\cos x$ is between $1-\frac{x^2}2$ and $1$. But so far, I just can't get it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Limit as $x$ approaches what? Related: what have you tried?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking since you didn't specify what $x$ is approaching in the limit.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't mention that I'm finding the limit of the sequence cos(2/x).

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. The limit of $\cos(\frac{2}{ x})$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ is 1 whereas the limit as $x \rightarrow 0$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that $1-\cos(\theta)=2\sin^2(\theta/2)$ so that $\cos(\theta)=1-2\sin^2(\theta/2)$.  Recalling that $|\sin(\theta)|\le |\theta|$, we see for $\theta =2/x$,

$$1-\frac12\left(\frac2x\right)^2\le \cos(2/x)\le 1$$

Can you proceed now?

Comment: Thank you very much Dr. MV. I've got it!

Comment: You're welcome,  My pleasure.

Comment: And feel free to up vote as you see fit,

Answer (score 0):

Hint: To prove what your instructor said, consider the Taylor expansion of $\cos(x)$:

$$
\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} +\cdots
$$

Comment: And we don't even need to know that expansion (see my solution for an elementary approach).  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV I agree. I like your approach! I just thought since this sounds like a high school problem, they taylor series might come to mind more quickly. Knowing $|\sin(x)| \leq |x|$ might not be completely obvious.

Comment: Do high school students learn Taylor series before they learn geometry and the squeeze theorem?

Comment: @Dr.MV I feel like squeeze theorem and taylor series are taught around the same-ish time, although I may be completely wrong.

Comment: I haven't learned Taylor expansion of cos(x). Maybe it will be covered in my later lessons. However, it is still helpful to know something new. Thank  you, gowrath!